# How can I make better performance when call PHP exec() function for pinging different hosts above 100 times?

Tags: php, html

collages I trying to find a solution for my case with slow rendering on the results from my PHP function when I call it many times for different hosts.

I want to make a pinging system based on the return from the exec() function (it's alive or it's not), I think that the problem comes from this that I call the exec() function many times for every host and the result delay above 15 seconds before server return all results and after that browser renders the information.  It's will be great if I can make this rendering time on max 3 seconds.

I use chrome and xampp for windows.

I try to do it with this code for exec() function :

```
?php
function Pinger($host) {
exec("ping -n 1 " . $host, $output, $result);
if ($result == 0)
return '<img src = "up.jpg">';
else
return'<img src = "down.jpg">';
}
?>
```

And call it from another php file with html like that:

```
<div id="hostname>
<?php echo Pinger('host');>
</div>
```

The number of the host is above 100.

Maybe if I use another faster function or something else?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not the speed of the function that's the issue, it's the fact that they're running one after the other after the other after the other, etc.... Running the pings in parallel would be faster

Comment: you could make a ping page which takes an ip in the post or get and have that called asynchronously 100x. you could easily do this in javascript with ajax and there probably will be functions for this in php too.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable would you give me an example no matter on which language? Thank you !

Comment: @nbglink `for(var i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get','ping.php?ip=' + ip[i],true);
xhr.send();
}`. And make a page called ping.php which pings the host given in the GET and returns the result in plaintext for the ajax call to receive

Answer (score 0):

The ping command has a lot of options to speed up response, e.g. set timeout (-w, -W) or set number of retries (-c). Try

> man ping

on the UNIX command line or see [the UNIX manual page online](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/ping/).

Aditionally of you know the IP address you can turn off DNS lookup (-n) which give some milliseconds as well.